# How to clone/duplicate an existing Android AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to clone/duplicate an existing Android Virtual Device. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Simple, in AVD Manager edit the AVD that you want to clone. Change the name and the button "Edit AVD" magically changes in "Create AVD"!

Comment: This no longer seems to work in latest version of Android Studio. After changing the name and saving, it just renamed the existing AVD and didn't create a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Edit AVD will not clone but create a new AVD without the data installed on the original device.

I found another way:

1. Go to `~/.android/avd` and copy `avd` folder of AVD you want to clone
2. Also copy .ini file of this AVD, open .ini file and change all paths to the new folder you have created
3. Go to the new folder; open the .ini file and change its paths, too

It should work now; when you reopen Android Studio, new AVD is cloned.

Comment: yep I had to do this in both `config.ini` and `hardware-qemu.ini` in the new folder. and also edited the AVD name/ID (`avd.name` and `avd.id` in `hardware-qemu.ini`) not sure if that's strictly required but seems sensible. and also made the same changes in the file `snapshots\default_boot\hardware.ini` within the AVD folder