# How to duplicate an Android Virtual Device (AVD) from the command line?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11141400/3515906), but from the command line. Maybe an option to [avdmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager)?